# Displaying the sum of a few columns that updates when any value in cells changes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, command, label

I'm trying to display the sum of the values in two or more columns (combined sum that is) in a label and although I can get a value when the data is loaded in, the sum lacks the feature to update when a value is changed in a cell while the application is running.

How do I implement this feature? I think it will be easier to add a button to sum and use a routed command.  I would prefer a buttonless way since the total sum is rather the point of the application and I don't want the user to keep pressing a button to update the sum when a value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise a `PropertyChange` notification for the `Sum` property anytime one of the values change, so the binding for the Sum knows it needs to re-evalute.

For example,

```
public int Value1
{
    get { return _value1; }
    set
    {
        if (_value1 != value)
        {
            _value1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Value1");
            RaisePropertyChanged("Sum");
        }
    }    
}
```

or

```
SomeDataObject.PropertyChanged += SomeDataObject_PropertyChanged;

void SomeDataObject_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Value1" || e.PropertyName == "Value2")
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged("Sum");
    }
}
```

To raise a property change notification, you need to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface

Also if you're binding to a `TextBox`, the default value for the `UpdateSourceTrigger` is `LostFocus`, so your setter and PropertyChange notification won't get run until after the TextBox loses focus. You can change the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the binding to `OnPropertyChange` if you want to re-evaluate it as the user types in their number.

Answer (score 0):

What control are you using?

Datagrid fo example has events that you can use when user finishes editing a cell after this event you can do a resum of the values and update the label,

Comment: I'm using a listview, or rather a control based on the listview that someone working previously on the same app made.

Comment: The user cannot edit the cells directly, the numbers in the cells are updated through comboxes on the window.

Comment: Wasn't that rather a comment than an answer; please consider moving it .... Thanks

Comment: PropertyChange is for UI updates on bound properties. Not for getting new values from the UI.